# Find all preceding sibling nodes until one is found with a specific child node attribute

Tags: xpath

I would like to get all table rows after a specific row identifier (an attribute on the row column) until that specific row identifier is found.

Here is the html I'm trying to parse:

```
  <tr>
    <td colspan="4">
      <h3>Header 1</h3>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Item desc - Header 1</td>
    <td>more info</td>
    <td>30</td>
    <td>500</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="4">
      <h3>Header 2</h3>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Item desc - header 2</td>
    <td>other</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>49</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Item 2 desc - header 2</td>
    <td>other 2</td>
    <td>65</td>
    <td>87</td>
  </tr>
```

I want to be able to grab the item under header 1 and stop when it finds header 2; then the items under header 2 and stop when it finds a header 3; etc.

Is this possible under xpath? I can't get it to only find the TR nodes until it finds a child node with a specific attribute (of colspan="4").

Comment: So you just want all the <td> nodes under each header?

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible under XPath 1.0. You somehow have to fixate the header tr, because you are trying to find all its following siblings whose first preceding header tr *is the original one*. Without the reference to the original header, everything is possible. But you probably work in some kind of a language that you can use to remember the value.

For example, in [xsh](http://p3rl.org/XML%3a%3aXSH2):

```
for my $x in //tr[td/@colspan="4"] {
    echo ($x/td/h3) ;
    for $x/following-sibling::tr[count(td)=4
                                 and preceding-sibling::tr[count(td)=1][1]=$x]
        echo "  " (td) ;
}
```

Output:

```
Header 1
   Item desc - Header 1 more info 30 500
Header 2
   Item desc - header 2 other 4 49
   Item 2 desc - header 2 other 2 65 87
```

Answer (score 1):

This might give you what you're looking for, not the most orthodox means though:

```
//*/tr/td[not(child::h3)]/ancestor::tr
```

This will give you all the `<td>` nodes within a `<tr>` that isn't a header block.

And you can specify the header with:

`//*/tr/td[not(child::h3/text()='Header 1')]/ancestor::tr`

Or a more general:

`//*/tr/td[not(child::h3[contains(text(),'Header')])]/ancestor::tr`